# LINQ and Reflection

Tags: jquery, linq, nhibernate, reflection

Here's a wild one.  I'm writing a universal entity editor using JQuery and NHibernate LINQ.  So far everything works great.  But now I'm trying to add sorting support.  Things have gotten tricky.  I want to tell it to sort on a property, but in the class, I will not know what kind of object it is until runtime.

Here's the code:

```
data =
    (from entity in _repository.FindAll()
    orderby entity.GetType().GetProperty(formData["sidx"]).GetValue(entity, null)
    select entity).ToList();
```

Here's the problem, I get a null pointer exception when I do this.  Any clues on how I can do what I want to do?  I suspect this issue is going to come up again when I do searching.

Comment: Where is the null reference occurring? (Stack trace.)

Comment: Have you tried writing it out in code syntax and breaking each step into its own line to find where the null point exception occurs?

Comment: Nick, can you explain your suggestion a bit more?  Thanks!

Comment: According to the stack trace, it's occurring here: at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.GetEntityName(ICriteria subcriteria, String propertyName)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Dynamic LINQ (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx, section **Downloading the LINQ Dynamic Query Library**) and specify the field to sort by as a string:

```
data = _repository.FindAll().OrderBy(formData["sidx"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks!  You'd think that this would be built into the standard libraries.  But then it'd be abused, I guess.  Any idea why descending doesn't work with Dynamic LINQ?

Comment: Try .OrderBy(formData["sidx"].ToString() + " desc").ToList() for descending order.  It is implemented as part of the expression in the .OrderBy call instead of extending the .OrderByDescending method.

Answer (score 0):

That should work provided `formData["sidx"]` specifies the name of an existing property with the proper case. Check what `formData["sidx"]` is returning and if it's in the correct case. I would start with hard-coding a real property name. If that works check `formData["sidx"]`.

For example, given a class with a property of `Name` your code would throw a `NullReferenceException` if you used `GetProperty("NaMe")`.